# How to wget a html file from a an administrative share on a Windows webserver

Tags: windows, unix, wget

Is there anyway I am able to use wget in Unix to transfer a html file from a Windows administrative share?

The file path I am trying to access is like the example:

www.webserv.com/share$/reportfolder/index.html

This is a very obtuse way of creating a monitoring script on a OS without the use of curl / Nagios / extra perl modules.

Any help given will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wget works only with http, https, and ftp protocols ([man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Overview))

if you need to access Windows files from Unix, you have several choices

1. FTP
2. You might look at Samba (http://www.samba.org)
3. You can use SSH